# Callbacks dictionary in python

Tags: python, function, callback

Is it possible to pass parameters to a function that it is call through it callbacks directory in python?

I was trying to do something like this and wishing to print "hello" at the end of the execution.

```
def f1(text):
    print text
    pass

def f2():
    pass

selector_by_type = {
    1: f1,
    2: f2
}
selector = selector_by_type.get(1)
selector("hello")
```

Comment: This code looks like it works. What's the problem? Also, the `pass` is unnecessary in the first function.

Comment: If you're using Python 3, you need parentheses for the call to print...

Comment: I guess what you want is `selector_by_type.get(1)("some string")`. Ah nevermind that's what you already do, then I don't understand the question.